# Assign rank to already sorted table

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I already have my desired table sorted using:

```
order by 
case when name = 'zzz' then '1' else null end asc
case when name = 'aaa' then '2' else null end asc
case when name = 'rrr' then '3' else null end asc
...
...
```

Now, I want to rank current order of my table to get sth like this:

```
new_rank    name
1           zzz
2           aaa
3           rrr
...         ...
...         ...
```

I tried `row_number() over()` but actually I do not have column to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

You repeat the `order by` in the `row_number()` statement:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by (case when name = 'zzz' then 1 end) asc,
                                   (case when name = 'aaa' then 2 end) asc,
                                   (case when name = 'rrr' then 3 end) asc
                         ) as seqnum
from . . .
```

Notes:

- There is no reason to use strings instead of numbers for the constants.
- `else NULL` is redundant in a `case` expression.
- The keys should be separated by comma for an `order by`, wherever it appears.

And, given that the `case` only uses constants, you might as well use only one:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by (case when name = 'zzz' then 1
                                         when name = 'aaa' then 2
                                         when name = 'rrr' then 3
                                         else 4
                                    end)
                         ) as seqnum
from . . .
```